# NameError - uninitialized constant Zip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zip, unzip, rubyzip

I am trying to unzip a file in my Spree plugin.

Defined the unzipping method in a module which looks like this.

```
module ImportImages
  class Zipper
    def self.unzip(zip, unzip_dir, remove_after = false)
      Zip::File.open(zip) do |zip_file|
        zip_file.each do |f|
          f_path=File.join(unzip_dir, f.name)
          FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(f_path))
          zip_file.extract(f, f_path) unless File.exist?(f_path)
        end
      end
      FileUtils.rm(zip) if remove_after
    end
  end
end
```

I have included the rubyzip gem in my Gemfile.

```
gem 'rubyzip'
gem 'zip-zip'
```

When trying to run it, I am getting the following error.

```
NameError - uninitialized constant ImportImages::Zipper::Zip:
```

I have tried every solution provided in stackoverflow and other sites. I tried downgrading the version of rubyzip which is 1.2.0 now and add `require 'zip'` or `require 'zip/zip'`. Both returned load error.

I have try adding `require 'zip/filesystem'` to the class. But got

```
LoadError - cannot load such file -- zip/zipfilesystem
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: `gem 'rubyzip', '< 1.0.0'` did you try this ?

Comment: Still getting the same error. If trying to add require, I am getting `cannot load such file -- zip/zipfilesystem`

Comment: https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip#important-note did you read this

Comment: just do require 'rubygems'
require 'zip'
not require any more

Comment: Yeah. I am not doing like that. Some solutions I found downgraded rubyzip and added these lines. Was trying that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's looking for a nested Constant. Change line `Zip::File.open(zip) do |zip_file|` with below:

```
::Zip::File.open(zip) do |zip_file|
```

It should work. 
Also make sure you require `rubygem`/`bundle setup`. Though in spree it should've already been done.

Comment: Now I am getting `NameError - uninitialized constant Zip`

Comment: @Aswathy: Make sure that in your Gemfile, the require is present. `gem "rubyzip", require: "zip"`.

Answer (score 6):

Include rubyzip in gem file in this way:

```
gem 'rubyzip', require: 'zip'
```

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32720548/nameerror-uninitialized-constant-unzipperzip-but-only-on-heroku-deploy-rail)

Answer (score 3):

Babar's answer is correct, but you also need to add `require 'zip'` in application_controller.rb

Comment: add require 'zip' similar to @montelis answer.